# Change Mask's opacity in Compositor?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, transparency

I'd like to change the opacity of this ink bleed that i've made using a couple of masks. 
Here's my node set[image]up:

I've tried adding a mix node and a set alpha node and attempted at changing the fac. value in hope of changing the opacity but it's not having an effect so i was hoping someone could help me out,

cheers for any help- much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adjusting the value of a mask is accomplished by adding a math node in multiply mode. The second value acts as a multiplier for the alpha.

[image].

Comment: Cheers appreciate the speedy concise response. Closing the books on this one.